# Struts2-jasperreports-plugin not functioning with newer version of japserreports

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports

I'm working with a struts 2.3.4.1 and am using the struts2-jasperreports-plugin to display a pre-compiled report. Fonts have been giving me issues, which I found was supposedly fixed in Jasperreports 6 (specifically issues with Calibri). Because I'm on a legacy system running java 6, the last version I can use is 6.2.2. But when I try to display my report, I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult.doExecute(JasperReportsResult.java:323)`, which seems to be a function called by the struts2-jasperreports-plugin that doesn't exist in jasperreports 6+. I've been looking around, but cannot find out if/how to change this behavior and am beginning to think that I need to update the version of my plugin.

Is there a way to change the function called by the plugin, or am I going to need to change the version of struts to get the behavior I expect? Is it possible to write an adapter for a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more troubleshooting, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/37864625/892327 in which an adapter  was made using existing code, which I got from https://web.archive.org/web/20180523111530/http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRLoader.java/, and added the missing `loadObject(String fileName)` function as an adapter for the `loadFromFile(String fileName)`. Which cleared the NoSuchMethodError.

However, the original issue `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:592` returned, which was "fixed" by changing the version of Java I was running, found at [Error generating JasperReport in Development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331075/error-generating-jasperreport-in-development-mode).

Because I'm working with a legacy system that runs on Java 6, I've given up since the original issue is JRE based and not a bad Jasperreports library or struts plugin.

Comment: @VíctorDueñasRobles I updated the link to the wayback machine's capture of that page.

Comment: Thanks! I discover the future version of struts 2.3.38 repair this bug. But now is only a Snaphot and you must compile de jar